# Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 (angular 5 on Ubuntu)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ubuntu

I'm trying to npm install on my Angular 5 project on my Ubuntu instance. I get the error:

> "Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0."

It appears to be some webpack issue where `module` is being misinterpreted.

Various solutions include

[using backticks](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1960)

[changing loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501723/unexpected-token-m-in-json-at-position-0-error)

But nowhere in my code do I have a place to implement those solutions (i.e. no `{"loaders": ""}` option?

The project runs fine locally, just not on Ubuntu. So I'm not sure what's going on. Thank you!!

Comment: using backticks. is it working?

Comment: I'm not sure where to use them because my logs in ubuntu don't tell me where the issue is occurring. Or maybe there's a way to do it that I don't know? Do you know how?Backticks seem to work for others sometime

Comment: If you are using lazy loading. Wherever you are defining routes using loadChildren propery. replace single quote with backtick.

Comment: Which file would that be located in? I can't find the 'loadChildren' anywhere in my project for some reason... which is fine cause it works locally but on ubuntu, where can I look for loadChildren? Thanks

Comment: might be, its not related to loadChildren then. some other issue

Comment: Resave the angular.json file as UTF8.

Comment: @bereketgebredingle how might exactly I do that? as in save it as angular.utf8 ? Like a file type? thanks