# How to save angular.json as UTF-8?

Tags: json, angular, utf-8, visual-studio-code

I am deploying an Angular project on Ubuntu and am running into [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563976/unexpected-token-m-in-json-at-position-0-angular-5-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment92069505_52563976) ("Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0.")

Someone suggested that I resave my angular.json file as UTF-8. I'm not exactly sure how to do that, do I need to add code or just change a file type?

If anyone knows how to do that (and why that might help) that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: UTF-8 is the file's [encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). What text editor are you using?

Comment: @DavidWalschots Hm yeah, I'm using VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the encoding of a file within vscode, do the following:

1. Open the file.
2. Look in the bottom right corner and press the name of the current encoding. In my example image below it is already UTF-8.
3. Select "save with encoding".
4. Pick the encoding you want to save the file with.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks so much! That didn't turn out to be my bug but it answered my question.